# Calendar of Activities for CiviCRM 4.7.3 on Wordpress 3.8.5?

Tags: wordpress, activities, calendar

Is there a way to get a calendar view of Activities for CiviCRM on Wordpress? I can easily get all of them in a sequential list using Find Activities or the dashboard widget, showing all the information I require (type, date and time, "with", and "assigned to"), but I want a week or month planner/calendar view to make it easier for users to see at-a-glance when meetings are.

The Contact Calendar extension does not work, giving an error message about being unable to connect to the site. In any case I don't think it's what I need, because I want more than just one person's calendar. There are extensions for CiviEvent and some discussion of calendars in Drupal here on StackExchange, but I've not found a way to get what I want in a CiviCRM/WP installation.

Comment: That's a seriously old version of WordPress. I'd be surprised if any plugin devs will support such an old version. You might want to consider upgrading before asking plugin devs for support.

Answer (score 1):

I use a Wordpress plugin called EveryCal+1 - it has a built in hook to civiEvents and works/looks really nice.

Answer (score 0):

As the Event Calendar already exists, it may be worth contacting the developer responsible to identify what would be involved in expanding it to also use activities of certain types.

Alternatively, you could commission a CiviCRM freelancer to do this expansion for you, on condition that they then publish that work to the wider community :)