# Event calendar for Civi 4.7.x?

Tags: civievent, extension, calendar

Related to [this earlier question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10483/calendar-of-activities-for-civicrm-4-7-3-on-wordpress-3-8-5) and [this earlier question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11084/can-this-event-calendar-extension-be-added-to-civicrm-core), I'm looking for a front-end event calendar. The most current extension I could find doesn't seem compatible beyond Civi 4.4, and we're running 4.7.16 ... on WordPress 4.7.2.

**Assuming others are running Civi 4.7 with some sort of working front-end event calendar, what's the most direct way to do this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it fits to your necessities but CiviEvent includes iCal for public events.

As you can see on CiviCRM user guide

> Select the Public Event box to include the event in promotional listings such as RSS feeds, iCal files or feeds, and event listing pages.

You can find more related information on how to use this functionality in this  forum topic [integration with iCal and/or Google Calendar - private calendars?](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=4160)